# Single r9 290 and 3 u2515h monitors

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

I am currently running two R9 290's in xfire powering three 1080p U2311H monitors.

As I don't game anywhere near as much as I thought I would, I am selling one of the R9 290's.

My question is, can one R9 290 power three U2515H monitors running 2560x1440?

I'm not talking about can it technically push the pixels but is it feasible in terms of connections as well?

The R9 290 is an XFX reference card with 2 dvi, 1 hdmi and 1 display port.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i known you can use all ports on this card. Additionally see this specification: http://www.amd.com/en-us/products/graphics/desktop/r9. Judging by you can use up to 6 displays.